# How to escape underscore in class options?

Tags: class-options, underscore

I have written a class for formatting reports. The class, Demo.cls, processes some options. Among them is a short title that is displayed at the top of every page using \fancyhdr. Short titles including underscore---use of which is beyond my control---results in a `Missing \endscname inserted.` error generated by `\ProcessOptions\relax`. The short title option works fine if it does not include underscores.

How can I pass underscores to the class?

I have included a MWE of the class, a non-working tex file and a working tex file.

Demo.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Demo}[2020/02/01 Demo report class]

% Demo.cls builds off of article with twoside option.
\LoadClass[twoside]{article}

% Class option to add "Confidential" in red text at the bottom of each page.
%   To use, call the Demo class such as \documentclass[confidential]{Demo}.
\newcommand\confidential{0}
\newcommand\no{0}
\newcommand\yes{1}
\DeclareOption{confidential}{ \renewcommand\confidential{1}  }
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Class option to print an abbreviated report title in the middle of the header on each page.
%   To use, call the Demo class such as \documentclass[shortTitle = {{This is my title}}]{Demo}.
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\def\shortTitle{}
\define@key{Demo.cls}{shortTitle}[]{\def\shortTitle{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{shortTitle}
\ProcessOptionsX

% Pull in required packages.
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\RequirePackage{datetime}

% Only display month an year, no date.
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{showdayofmonth=false}

% Demo-style header with project name and date.
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\normalsize \shortTitle}
\fancyhead[R]{\normalsize \monthname[\the\month], \the\year}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{ \thepage }
\if \confidential 1
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{ \textbf{\large \textcolor{red}{Confidential}} }
\fi
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Non-working tex file:

```
\documentclass[shortTitle = {{Title\_with\_underscore}}]{Demo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Other section}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Working tex file:

```
\documentclass[shortTitle = {{Title without underscore}}]{Demo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Other section}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow... Latex never let me down like this before.. Ever. How do I report this as a bug to devs?